# Creating objects and enumerating them during runtime

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to programming and this question is probably very basic but;

I've been assigned with a homework which in one part asks me to;

Write a main program that reads commands from standard input and executes them. Every command 
corresponds to a function from the above modules/classes. Every time a list is created, it will be assigned a 
unique number. You can assume that at most 10 lists will be created by the input. The first list is assigned 
number 0 and the last one is assigned number at most 9

I already coded modules / classes (a linkedlist class, a linkedlist module, an array class and an array module) But I dont know how its even possible to create them automaticly and assign them a value, I dont even know where to start. I cannot use an array to store created lists because they belong to different variable types.
Any tips is appreciated.

Comment: I find your question unclear. What you mean module/class is? What is the connection between commands and making a list? What should list contain?

Comment: Have you studied classes and inheritance yet? You could make all your lists inherit from one base class, and then store them in a size-10 array of your base class type. I think the idea of your homework is precisely that - make an array of 10, and every time a list is created, you're given some number `i` and so need to place the new list into `array[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static variable which is increased everytime you create a list, and use this variable to identify the created list :

```
static int id = 0;

FunctionThatCreateList {
/* Your creation code */
SetId(id);
id++;
}
```

That way, everytime you create a list, it's id will be set and you're sure it'll be unique

Comment: My question may not be clear because I am not clear  about it myself.
I tried to create a struct including all 4 item type, but one of my classes require a variable for default constructor and I cannot create it in a struct. I dont even know what that means, nvm.